# How do I find a compatible replacement for my rear derailleur?

Tags: derailleur

I need to replace rear derailleur that was broken in an accident.  The derailleur is Suntour with lettering stamped on inside - Maeda Ind. VIA HB.

How do I find a compatible replacement?

Comment: how many gears?

Comment: If its friction shifted, you can put in any new derailleur with sufficient capacity (likely, an Acera 8 speed derailleur is a good choice) [I've also heard that it works with indexing sloppily for 7 speed systems, but no first hand evidence].

Comment: I cleaned up your edit a bit for better readability and changed the title to better reflect the updated question. If you feel I have changed the nature of your question, feel free to edit it further.

Comment: You need to say how many speeds it is. (Maeda Ind. is just the parent company of suntour) and you need to say what kind of shifters you have.

Comment: @Batman, don't 7 and 8 speed cassettes have the same chain spacing? I can't see why the indexing wouldn't work.

Comment: The problem with mixing different manufacturers is the cable pull - how much the shifter pulls the cable in order to move the derailleur. If its friction, it doesn't matter since you just move the lever continuously, but if its indexed, it does since the detents may not match up between manufacturers.